# Windows Server 2008 R2 permissions: Users can't write despite being administrators

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

We just set up a new R2 server and created a bunch of local user accounts on it that are part of the administrator's group.

We then set permissions on some shares and folders to allow FULL CONTROL to anyone from the administrator's group.

However, the users cannot write to these folders when logged on. On some folders on the C:\ they are prompted for consent in order to gain permission to read them.

Any ideas? Are there any tools that would help me troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the UAC.  You should use a different group to give out permissions or disable the UAC.  The administrator privilege is filtered away to protect yourself.

See: [Administrator File Modification Privilege](https://serverfault.com/questions/4696/administrator-file-modification-privilege/5173#5173)